# iFrame loading by default

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, console

I have a simple yet complex confusing question.
I have an iframe in my HTML code which is set to a function with onload attribute. The function goes like this:

```
var refresh = 0
console.log(refresh)
document.getElementById('iframe_submit').onload = function () {
    refresh++;
    console.log(refresh);
}
```

Now this iframe is targeted when a user clicks on the Submit button of a form in the site. The problem is, when I am running the code from VS Code, the refresh value is printed like this:

```
1
2 (On clicking the submit button)
```

But on running the same in my published site, the following output comes:

```
0
1 (On clicking the submit button)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening! Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your `refresh++;` and `console.log(refresh);` statements are written in the same order on both your dev and prod scripts?

Comment: I have copied the statements from the actual code itself. Just I have put an extra console.log() whenever the page loads which prints the first value of refresh